# Reverse JSON pretty print with Jackson

Tags: java, json

I know I can reformat JSON objects in Java (using Jackson, GSON, etc.) to go from

```
{"a":"b", "c":"d"}
```

to

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

But how do I go convert a JSON object back to one-object-per-line format, i.e how do I get from

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

to

```
{"a":"b", "c":"d"}
```

in Java using an existing pretty-printer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following URL:
[Jackson Serialization features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features)

This will show you how you can disable features, like indent output on a per call basis, even if you are reusing the same object that has been configured for pretty printing.

I think Pretty Print is a Jackson 1.x nomenclature though... and you should be looking for SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT

```
    @Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String s = "{ \"a\" : \"b\" ,\n \"c\" : \"d\"}";
    Object x = mapper.readValue(s, Object.class);
    ObjectWriter w = mapper.writer();

    // Indented
    System.out.println(w.writeValueAsString(x));

    // Single Line
    System.out.println(w.without(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writeValueAsString(x));
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer. Michael's code works, too, and is shorter, actually, but I like the explicitness of deactivating INDENT_OUTPUT in this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  You'll also note that the other answer has an object of JsonNode ... and it's implementation of toString();  Not all objects will use the same toString(). you can use this method with any object that the writer can serialize.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Jackson, it should work out of the box using:

```
String prettyJson = "{ \"a\" : \"b\" ,\n \"c\" : \"d\"}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode;
try {
    jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(prettyJson, JsonNode.class);
    System.out.println(jsonNode.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: He's asking how to do this when using a writer that has already been instantiated and configured for indented output.

Comment: I'm asking in general how to do this. I don't mind if a new writer has to be created.